# How to Pause and Resume a YouTube video using voice commands on Windows

Tags: youtube, windows

I would like to be able to pause and resume a YouTube video using voice commands. How can I set this up on Windows with YouTube running in a browser? I'm looking for a solution that does not require YouTube to have the immediate focus.